# rotate image if needed with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a preview spot to show a preview of the image before uploading, the problem is when you  choose an image from your phone it appears sideways. How can I rotate the image if it needs to be rotated?

my javascript to show the preview:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)

                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }

</script>
```

and the html

```
<img src="images/Your_Picture_Here.png" alt="" title="" class="prod_image" id = "blah"/>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest you to take a look at the github project called [JavaScript-Load-Image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image). Every thing is there to help you out with your orientation problem.
There is an online demo that you can see [here](http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/).

You could use code as follow:

```
document.getElementById('file-input').onchange = function (e) {
    var loadingImage = loadImage(
        e.target.files[0],
        function (img) {
            document.getElementById("blah").src = img.toDataURL();
        },
        {orientation: 1}
    );
    if (!loadingImage) {
        // Alternative code ...
    }
};
```

Please note the option `orientation: 1` to make your image well rotated.

There is 8 valid values in EXIF for the orientation, see below the letter F for the 8 different value:

```
1       2       3       4       5           6           7           8

000000  000000      00  00      0000000000  00                  00  0000000000
00          00      00  00      00  00      00  00          00  00      00  00
0000      0000    0000  0000    00          0000000000  0000000000          00
00          00      00  00
00          00  000000  000000
```

Comment: I tried this and it almost works! But I can get the image to go into my id the image is put at the bottom of the body. When i do             `document.getElementById("blah").appendChild(img);` nothing happens at all..

Comment: @BluGeni Try `document.getElementById("blah").src = img;` instead of `document.body.appendChild(img);`

Comment: I get `[object%20HTMLCanvasElement] 404 (Not Found)`  with that

Comment: Ok, i just reread the doc for this feature. It seems to return a canvas while using the option `orientation`. So this should work: `document.getElementById("blah").src = img.toDataURL();`. I'm sorry that i cannot test it out myself.

Comment: @morgul after reorienting the image, how can I replace it in the input field so that the changed image gets submitted in the form?

Comment: @Bej, you cannot replace the input file directly, but you can send the new image using a hidden input field. This answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51118947/2774496

Answer (score -2):

A great way to do it is: **let the browser do it**.
You use CSS / HTML5 instead of Javascript.

```
.image_rotated_by_90 {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
}
```

You can append the class `image_rotated_by_90` dynamically to your rotated images in js.
Apply it by doing

```
$('#my_image').addClass('image_rotated_by_90');
```

Comment: `#` is not a class, it's an id.  You want `.image_rotated_by_90`.

Comment: @aoeu so i added the code to my css do i need to reference it ? or how to I make it work?

Comment: @BluGeni I added a snippet

Comment: @aoeu ok this worked! but it moved my image over to the right, because of the rotate?

Comment: @BluGeni Play around with the `translateY` to fit your needs. Please also accept the answer, if it helped you :)

Comment: This answer doesnt work because when I upload a pic not from a phone it still rotates it. I dont want to always rotate. I need to determine if it needs rotated.

Comment: Then you will need to read the Orientation tag in the image's EXIF header, draw it onto a canvas, rotated appropriately, and then turn that canvas into a data URI which you will then use for the `<img>`'s `src` attribute.

Comment: @aoeu Does your answer, answer my question "How can I rotate the image if it needs to be rotated?" maybe im doing something wrong but from what I can tell is that it will always rotate the image, I need a way to do it only if it needs to be rotated using the image data.